# How to handle a Button click event

Tags: python, events, button, tkinter

I'm just learning Python and I have the base concept down, and already a few command line programs. I'm now learning how to create GUIs with Tkinter.

I created a simple GUI to accept some user information from a `Entry` widget, and then, when the user clicks submit, it should pop up a dialog.

The dialog should ask for the *first name* and *last name*.

The problem is that I don't know how to handle the event when the user clicks submit.

Here's my code:

```
from Tkinter import *

class GUI(Frame):

    def __init__(self,master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.grid()

        self.fnameLabel = Label(master, text="First Name")
        self.fnameLabel.grid()

        self.fnameEntry = Entry(master)
        self.fnameEntry.grid()

        self.lnameLabel = Label(master, text="Last Name")
        self.lnameLabel.grid()

        self.lnameEntry = Entry(master)
        self.lnameEntry.grid()

        self.submitButton = Button(self.buttonClick, text="Submit")
        self.submitButton.grid()


    def buttonClick(self, event):
        """ handle button click event and output text from entry area"""
        pass


if __name__ == "__main__":
    guiFrame = GUI()
    guiFrame.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 10):

You already had your event function. Just correct your code to:

```
   """Create Submit Button"""
    self.submitButton = Button(master, command=self.buttonClick, text="Submit")
    self.submitButton.grid()

def buttonClick(self):
    """ handle button click event and output text from entry area"""
    print('hello')    # do here whatever you want
```

This is the same as in @Freak's answer except for the `buttonClick()` method is now outside the class `__init__` method. The advantage is that in this way you can call the action programmatically. This is the conventional way in OOP-coded GUI's.

Answer (score 4):

You should specify a *handler*, or a function, that is called when you click the Button. You can do this my assigning the name (not calling the function) of the function to the property `command` of your Button.

For example:

```
self.submitButton = Button(self.buttonClick, text="Submit", command=buttonClick)
```

Note the absence of `()` when assigning `buttonClick` as the `command` property of `self.submitButton`.

Note that you don't need the second parameter called `event` in your handler/function `buttonClick()`.

Comment: Thanks for this. I forgot that you can use function names without calling them with the ending "( )". I was wondering why the process I intended to call from a button kept popping at the same time as the GUI and this was it. I'm pretty new to GUIs

Answer (score 4):

I found a pretty good reference called [`Thinking in Tkinter`](http://thinkingtkinter.sourceforge.net), and I butchered it up a bit. I tried to fit it for what you wanted.

```
from tkinter import *

class GUI(Frame):

    def __init__(self,master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.grid()

        self.fnameLabel = Label(master, text="First Name")
        self.fnameLabel.grid()

        self.fnameEntry = StringVar()
        self.fnameEntry = Entry(textvariable=self.fnameEntry)
        self.fnameEntry.grid()

        self.lnameLabel = Label(master, text="Last Name")
        self.lnameLabel.grid()

        self.lnameEntry = StringVar()
        self.lnameEntry = Entry(textvariable=self.lnameEntry)
        self.lnameEntry.grid()

        def buttonClick():
            print("You pressed Submit!")
            print(self.fnameEntry.get() + " " + self.lnameEntry.get() +",
                  you clicked the button!")

        self.submitButton = Button(master, text="Submit", command=buttonClick)
        self.submitButton.grid()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    guiFrame = GUI()    
    guiFrame.mainloop()
```