# how to put a code that if a button is pressed, a message pops up?

Tags: python, tkinter

Basically I learnt Python today, I'm trying to make my first project, which is gonna be a hangman game, nothing special, just something to start making.
On to my question.. how do I pop up a message if a key is pressed? I know it's print("Message"). 
But how do I "detect" if a key is pressed? 
This is the code(the code is not advanced, as I said.. I started learning today):

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

topFrame = Frame(root)
topFrame.pack()
bottomFrame = Frame(root)
bottomFrame.pack(side=BOTTOM)

A = Button(topFrame, text="A", bg="green", fg="white")
B = Button(topFrame, text="B", bg="green", fg="white")
C = Button(topFrame, text="C", bg="green", fg="white")
D = Button(topFrame, text="D", bg="green", fg="white")
E = Button(topFrame, text="E", bg="green", fg="white")
F = Button(topFrame, text="F", bg="green", fg="white")
G = Button(topFrame, text="G", bg="green", fg="white")
H = Button(topFrame, text="H", bg="green", fg="white")
I = Button(topFrame, text="I", bg="green", fg="white")
J = Button(topFrame, text="J", bg="green", fg="white")
K = Button(topFrame, text="K", bg="green", fg="white")
L = Button(topFrame, text="L", bg="green", fg="white")
M = Button(topFrame, text="M", bg="green", fg="white")
N = Button(topFrame, text="N", bg="green", fg="white")
O = Button(topFrame, text="O", bg="green", fg="white")
P = Button(topFrame, text="P", bg="green", fg="white")
Q = Button(topFrame, text="Q", bg="green", fg="white")
R = Button(topFrame, text="R", bg="green", fg="white")
S = Button(topFrame, text="S", bg="green", fg="white")
T = Button(topFrame, text="T", bg="green", fg="white")
U = Button(topFrame, text="U", bg="green", fg="white")
V = Button(topFrame, text="V", bg="green", fg="white")
W = Button(topFrame, text="W", bg="green", fg="white")
X = Button(topFrame, text="X", bg="green", fg="white")
Y = Button(topFrame, text="Y", bg="green", fg="white")
Z = Button(topFrame, text="Z", bg="green", fg="white")




A.pack(side=LEFT)
B.pack(side=LEFT)
C.pack(side=LEFT)
D.pack(side=LEFT)
E.pack(side=LEFT)
F.pack(side=LEFT)
G.pack(side=LEFT)
H.pack(side=LEFT)
I.pack(side=LEFT)
J.pack(side=LEFT)
K.pack(side=LEFT)
L.pack(side=LEFT)
M.pack(side=LEFT)
N.pack(side=LEFT)
O.pack(side=LEFT)
P.pack(side=LEFT)
Q.pack(side=LEFT)
R.pack(side=LEFT)
S.pack(side=LEFT)
T.pack(side=LEFT)
U.pack(side=LEFT)
V.pack(side=LEFT)
W.pack(side=LEFT)
X.pack(side=LEFT)
Y.pack(side=LEFT)
Z.pack(side=LEFT)


if A is pressed:
    print("Wrong letter, that's a strike!")





root.mainloop()
```

I tried

if A is pressed:
    print("Wrong letter, that's a strike!")

it doesn't work.

Comment: This link may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6874525/how-to-handle-a-button-click-event

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to handle a Button click event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6874525/how-to-handle-a-button-click-event)

Answer (score 1):

When you click a button, tkinter main loop capture the event and look for something to with it.To connect our code with the button click event, **we should pass what to be run when the event occurs through the command parameter.** First you have to define what we want to happen when button clicked.

As print function displays the output in the console and not in the gui it is pointless to use print() to display the output. It is much better if we used a label to display the output in the gui itself.

```
def on_click():
    label.config(text = 'Wrong letter! that's a strike')
```

for this to work, we should add a label to the gui. This can be done via

```
label = Label(root,font = 'size,20')
label.pack(side = 'bottom')
```

Finally we can configure the button code.

```
A = Button(topFrame, text="A", bg="green", fg="white", command=on_click)
```

This will make the text appear on the label when we click the button.

Answer (score 0):

```
...
def callback():
    print("Wrong letter, that's a strike!")    
...
A = Button(topFrame, text="A", bg="green", fg="white", command=callback)
...
```

The above should work. http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/ is a good Tkinter resource, although I don't know if learning a library like Tkinter is a good place to start learning Python.

Comment: Shouldn't you define `callback` before you use it in `A`? It's going to raise a `NameError` by running your example.

Comment: Yes, of course. Wasn't thinking I guess. Either way, that wasn't the point.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the command attribute to the button using which you want to print the line.
I have done it for Button A below:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

topFrame = Frame(root)
topFrame.pack()
bottomFrame = Frame(root)
bottomFrame.pack(side=BOTTOM)

A = Button(topFrame, text="A", bg="green", fg="white", command=lambda: print("Wrong letter, that's a strike!"))
B = Button(topFrame, text="B", bg="green", fg="white")
C = Button(topFrame, text="C", bg="green", fg="white")
D = Button(topFrame, text="D", bg="green", fg="white")
E = Button(topFrame, text="E", bg="green", fg="white")
F = Button(topFrame, text="F", bg="green", fg="white")
G = Button(topFrame, text="G", bg="green", fg="white")
H = Button(topFrame, text="H", bg="green", fg="white")
I = Button(topFrame, text="I", bg="green", fg="white")
J = Button(topFrame, text="J", bg="green", fg="white")
K = Button(topFrame, text="K", bg="green", fg="white")
L = Button(topFrame, text="L", bg="green", fg="white")
M = Button(topFrame, text="M", bg="green", fg="white")
N = Button(topFrame, text="N", bg="green", fg="white")
O = Button(topFrame, text="O", bg="green", fg="white")
P = Button(topFrame, text="P", bg="green", fg="white")
Q = Button(topFrame, text="Q", bg="green", fg="white")
R = Button(topFrame, text="R", bg="green", fg="white")
S = Button(topFrame, text="S", bg="green", fg="white")
T = Button(topFrame, text="T", bg="green", fg="white")
U = Button(topFrame, text="U", bg="green", fg="white")
V = Button(topFrame, text="V", bg="green", fg="white")
W = Button(topFrame, text="W", bg="green", fg="white")
X = Button(topFrame, text="X", bg="green", fg="white")
Y = Button(topFrame, text="Y", bg="green", fg="white")
Z = Button(topFrame, text="Z", bg="green", fg="white")




A.pack(side=LEFT)
B.pack(side=LEFT)
C.pack(side=LEFT)
D.pack(side=LEFT)
E.pack(side=LEFT)
F.pack(side=LEFT)
G.pack(side=LEFT)
H.pack(side=LEFT)
I.pack(side=LEFT)
J.pack(side=LEFT)
K.pack(side=LEFT)
L.pack(side=LEFT)
M.pack(side=LEFT)
N.pack(side=LEFT)
O.pack(side=LEFT)
P.pack(side=LEFT)
Q.pack(side=LEFT)
R.pack(side=LEFT)
S.pack(side=LEFT)
T.pack(side=LEFT)
U.pack(side=LEFT)
V.pack(side=LEFT)
W.pack(side=LEFT)
X.pack(side=LEFT)
Y.pack(side=LEFT)
Z.pack(side=LEFT)

root.mainloop()
```