# How to run a set of code when mouse button is clicked?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I want to run my code when Button_1 is pressed.
So something like :

```
def buttonPress(self, event):
    (Not sure what to put here)

def playGamesWith(self, aiPlayer):
 if buttonPress == True:
    ...
```

Would this be the right approach? Create a function that checks for the event then returns true when it is pressed? If so, how would I do that?

Comment: I think what you are trying to find, this link contains the same.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6874525/how-to-handle-a-button-click-event

Comment: This is covered in proably every single tkinter tutorial and documentation site out there. Why do you need our help?

Answer (score 0):

If your window is called `root`, use

```py
root.bind("<Button-1>", handler)
```

where `handler` is a function that should be executed when button 1 is pressed.

Comment: Where would this line be located? In my main() ?

Comment: @RonnyValtonen Where you create the root window (`Tk()`).