# How to count the number of clicks for button

Tags: python, tkinter

How to count the number of clicks for CAT or DOG button in my program and save to log.txt

```
from Tkinter import *

import Tkinter as tk

import sys 

stdoutOrigin=sys.stdout 
sys.stdout = open("log.txt", "w")

master = Tk()
Label(master, text='Who is your favourate animal ?? ').grid(row=0)


Button(master, text='CAT' ,).grid(row=1, sticky=W, pady=4)
Button(master, text='DOG' ,).grid(row=1,column=1,sticky=W, pady=4)
mainloop()

sys.stdout.close()
sys.stdout=stdoutOrigin
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this script is the best one to overwrite a number in a file, but you can try it. If your file is empty, it will create lines (for ex : `dog = 0`), and if it exists it will increment it (for ex : `dog = 1`) when you click on the button.

I also remove your `from Tkinter import *`, and instead I replaced `Button` by `tk.Button` for all widgets.

```
def save_in_file(animal):
    f = open("log.txt", "r+")

    animal_exists = False
    data = f.read()

    # separate the file into lines
    lines = data.split("\n") # list of lines : ['dog = 2', 'cat = 1']
    for i, v in enumerate(lines):
        # separate the lines into words
        words = v.split() # list of words : ['dog', '=', '3']
        if animal in words:
            animal_exists = True

            # here we search for the "number_to_increment"
            number_to_increment = words[-1]

            # we convert "number_to_increment" into integer, then add 1
            new_number = str(int(number_to_increment) +1)

            # we convert "new_number" back to string
            words[-1] = new_number

        # concatenate words to form the new line
        lines[i] = " ".join(words)

    # creates a new line with "animal = 0" if "animal" is not in file
    if not animal_exists:
        if lines[0] == "":
            lines.remove("")
        lines.append("{} = 0".format(animal))

    # concatenate all lines to get the whole text for new file
    data = "\n".join(lines)

    f.close()

    # open file with write permission
    f = open("log.txt", "wt")

    # overwrite the file with our modified data
    f.write(data)
    f.close()

def cat():
    save_in_file("cat")

def dog():
    save_in_file("dog")

import tkinter as tk

master = tk.Tk()
tk.Label(master, text='Who is your favourate animal ?? ').grid(row=0)

tk.Button(master, text='CAT', command=cat).grid(row=1, sticky="w", pady=4)
tk.Button(master, text='DOG', command=dog).grid(row=1,column=1,sticky="w", pady=4)
master.mainloop()
```

Output :

```
# log.txt
dog = 2
cat = 1
```

Comment: Thank you so much Dear requirement was same as u code.

But I did not understand that what you did in def save_in_file(animal): 

Can you explain line by line if possible?

Comment: I updated my answer with comments, tell me if it's still not clear

Answer (score 1):

```
cats = 0
dogs = 0
def cat():
    with open("log.txt").read() as contents:
        file = open("log.txt", "w")
        file.write(str(int(contents.split()[0]) + 1) + "\n" + contents.split()[1])
        file.close()
def dog():
    with open("log.txt").read() as contents:
        file = open("log.txt", "w")
        file.write(contents.split()[0] + "\n" + str(int(contents.split()[1]) + 1))
        file.close()
Button(master, text='CAT' , command=cat).grid(row=1, sticky=W, pady=4)
Button(master, text='DOG' , command=dog).grid(row=1,column=1,sticky=W, pady=4)
```

Comment: Hi,

I am getting below error, please clarify

Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\naman\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:/Users/naman/OneDrive/Desktop/tst or.py", line 13, in cat
    with open("log.txt").read() as contents:
AttributeError: __enter__

Comment: You need to make a log.txt file containing two zeros on separate lines before you start

Comment: `with open("log.txt").read() as contents:` will raise exception because `str` does not support `context manager` feature.

Answer (score 1):

You can also just make a command that adds one to a variable every click.

Comment: Your answer is quite short you should explain it before you start getting downvotes.

Comment: Please elaborate

Comment: sure, you need you button to do something on click so you give it a command check this out [link] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6874525/how-to-handle-a-button-click-event and see how they do there buttons