# Python 3.8. Why I'm missing 2 required positional arguments: 'event' and 'cmb'?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, combobox

When I use comboboxes the script prints ok. But when I use button "get list of choices" I receive the error message "get_combo_choice() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'event' and 'cmb'". I can't figure it out. Thanks for any hint.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import  ttk
from tkinter import Tk
from tkinter import Button

root = Tk()
my_heroes = ['Zidane', 'Ronaldo', 'Messi']
position = ['The One!', 'more or less','the bad']
# result =[]

# def get_combo_choice(event, cmb):
#     result.append(cmb.get())
#     print(result)
result =[None, None, None]
best = []

# Here's the alternative 
def get_combo_choice(event, cmb):
    i = best.index(event.widget)
    result[i] = cmb.get()
    print('result-->', result)    
    print('i-->', i)
    print('event.widget-->', event.widget)
    print('cmb.get-->', cmb.get())
    print('result[i]-->', result[i])
          
          
          
for index, heroe in enumerate(my_heroes):
    var = tk.StringVar()
    bestPlayers = ttk.Combobox(root,values=position, textvariable=var, state="readonly")
    best.append(bestPlayers)
    bestPlayers.grid(row=0 + index, column=1,padx=(15,25))
    
    label = tk.Label(root, text = heroe)
    label.grid(row=0 + index, column=0,padx=(15,25))

    bestPlayers.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>",lambda event, cmb=var: get_combo_choice(event, cmb))

    
    button = tk.Button(root, text ="get list of choices", command = get_combo_choice)
    button.grid(row=4, column=0,padx=(15,25))

root.mainloop()
```

And the error is:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python\python38\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
TypeError: get_combo_choice() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'event' and 'cmb'
```

Comment: As the error said, callback for `command` option of a button expect no argument.

Comment: You created a button in each iteration and put it in *same cell (row=4, column=0)*, so only the last button can be seen.  Should the button be created outside the for loop instead?

Answer (score 1):

[UPD]

You can use the following:

```py
button = tk.Button(root, text ="get list of choices")
button.grid(row=4, column=0,padx=(15,25))
button.bind("<Button-1>", lambda event, cmd=var: get_combo_choice(event, var))
```

Since your function `get_combo_choice(event, cmd)` has two positional arguments, you need to feed them as while calling the function:

This is raising different error which is something to do with best.index

```py
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/nishanth.reddy/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "<ipython-input-11-e63f934a14cb>", line 43, in <lambda>
    button.bind("<Button-1>", lambda event, cmd=var: get_combo_choice(event, var))
  File "<ipython-input-11-e63f934a14cb>", line 19, in get_combo_choice
    i = best.index(event.widget)
ValueError: <tkinter.Button object .!button3> is not in list
```

If your function requires arguments, you can use lambda, like:

```py
button = tk.Button(
    root, 
    text ="get list of choices", 
    command=lambda : get_combo_choice(event, cmb) # will raise NameError
)
```

But the main point here is that `event` is not passed when the button is clicked. REF: [How to handle a Button click event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6874525/how-to-handle-a-button-click-event/6875555)

```py
python def button_press_handle(callback=None):
    if callback:         
        callback() # Where exactly the method assigned to btn['command'] is being callled
```

If you want an `event` object for sure, then maybe you can create a dummy local event object and pass it while calling your function.

Creating dummy event object:

```py
        e = tkinter.Event()
        e.serial = 12345
        e.num = '??'
        e.height = '??'
        e.keycode = '??'
        e.state = 0
        e.time = 123456789
        e.width = '??'
        e.x = '??'
        e.y = '??'
        e.char = ''
        e.keysym = '??'
        e.keysym_num = '??'
        e.type = '100' # or tk.EventType.ButtonPress
        e.widget = '??'
        e.x_root = '??'
        e.y_root = '??'
        e.delta = 0
```

One way to get button clicked event is to use `button.bind("<Button-1>", lambda event: get_combo_choice(event, None))`

Comment: Where can you get the `event` and `cmb` objects?

Comment: When the button is clicked, looks like the following method is called

```python
def button_press_handle(callback=None):
    if callback:
        callback() # Where exactly the method assigned to btn['command'] is being callled
```

where `callback` is the command argument.

Comment: Yes I know, but you will get exception: `NameError: name 'event' is not defined`.

Comment: You don't get `event` for button click, refer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6874525/how-to-handle-a-button-click-event/6875555

Comment: If you have arguments that you want to send, then you can use lambda as I mentioned.

Comment: But your answer has used `event` inside the lambda.  Did you try your answer?

Comment: Yes, it gives an error, because the event doesn't exist, If I have created an `event` and `cmb` before my function then it works.

Comment: How can you create the `event` object?

Comment: ```
        e = tk.Event()
        e.serial = 12345
        e.num = '??'
        e.height = '??'
        e.keycode = '??'
        e.state = 0
        e.time = 123456789
        e.width = '??'
        e.x = '??'
        e.y = '??'
        e.char = ''
        e.keysym = '??'
        e.keysym_num = '??'
        e.type = '100'
        e.widget = '??'
        e.x_root = '??'
        e.y_root = '??'
        e.delta = 0
```

Comment: Then you should update your answer and see whether OP accepts it or not.  But from my point of view, creating a dummy `event` object is not a good answer.

Comment: Actually, there is no `event` object sent when a button is clicked, so there is no point in calling a function that needs it as a positional argument, ideally, we should call some function that doesn't need any positional arguments, if someone needs the button pressed event, then I was saying, may be we can create a dummy event.

Comment: @acw1668 Can you review the answer now?

Comment: The argument I want to print with button is result after comboboxes been chosen.

Comment: Dear colleagues,

if I can't get the list of comboboxes result (in loop) clicking a button, anyone has idea of how, anyway, to get the list of chosen comboboxes, lets say : ['more or less', 'The One!','the bad'].
By the way, it is curious how difficult is to get the list of chosen options in comboboxes. It seems so obvious that this list is important that should be a simple line or command, exclusively to return it to us. Observation: I'm not criticizing any of you, on the contrary, thank you all. I'm just commenting about python structure. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The result is already stored in your global variable `result` right? So you can create one more function and associate it to button click event and it can use the result, if you wanted to remember the choices as well, maybe while storing the result, also remember which index is in some global dict or a tuple.

Comment: Just use a function `def get_result(): print(result)` and use `button = tk.Button(root, text ="get list of choices", command = get_result)` you can also use this function outside of loop as it prints out the result whenever someone clicks get_list_of_choices button

Answer (score 0):

I reduce to the "minimum" size and following your orientation it is working now, "huge" thank YOU:

```
from tkinter import  ttk
from tkinter import Tk
from tkinter import Button

root = Tk()
my_heroes = ['Zidane', 'Ronaldo', 'Messi']
position = ['The One!', 'more or less','the bad']


def get_combo_choice(event, cmb):
    i = best.index(event.widget)
    result[i] = cmb.get()


def get_result(): 
    print(result)  
    
    
result =[None, None, None]
best = []
       
combobox_in_loop = ['None']*3
combobox_get = []            
for index, heroe in enumerate(my_heroes):
    var = tk.StringVar()
    bestPlayers = ttk.Combobox(root,values=position, textvariable=var, state="readonly")
    best.append(bestPlayers)
    bestPlayers.grid(row=0 + index, column=1,padx=(15,25))
    bestPlayers.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>",lambda event, cmb=var: get_combo_choice(event, cmb))
#     bestPlayers.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", lambda event:callbackFunc(event))
    combobox_in_loop.append(bestPlayers) # = saves names of comboboxes
    combobox_get.append(bestPlayers.get())
    

button = tk.Button(root,text ="this is wrong", command=get_combo_choice )
button.grid(row=4, column=0)

button2 = tk.Button(root, text ="correct: get list of choices", command = get_result)
button2.grid(row=5, column=0)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: result--> ['the bad', 'The One!', 'more or less']